# pdf2swf using MAC OS Batch command or Apple script

Tags: bash, shell, applescript, batch-processing, pdf2swf

How do I write a batch process on the Mac for pdf2swf, I want to convert all pdfs in a folder into swf. But pdf2swf doesn't have a option to convert a folder of pdfs to swfs, you have to do it one at a time. I'm not sure how if I should use a Apple script or a Shell script, either one I'm not sure how to get or assign a file name variable.

```
pdf2swf file_name_variable.pdf -o file_name_variable.swf -T 9 -f
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up Terminal and do something like this:

```
$ for f in `find /path/to/my/pdf/directory -name \*.pdf` ; do
>   echo "Processing $f..."
>   pdf2swf $f -o ${f/.pdf/.swf} -T 9 -f
> done
```

Comment: Thanks Paul R, this worked! You saved me from hours of scratching my head.